# Array with only specfic values in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I want to have an array which can contain only specific value

for example `socialService` would be an array which can only contain value such as `facebook`, `twitter`, `github`, `linkedin` and few more.

The goal is to only initialise service which are passed in the array.

In typescript how Can I specify an array which can only have certain values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using a [string literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html#string-literal-types). Example:

```
type SocialService = "facebook" | "twitter" | "github";
const arr: SocialService[] = [];
arr.push("github"); // Yay
arr.push("foo"); // Error
```